# Spark Scala - how to use $"col" and S string interpolation together?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, string-formatting

I want to achieve this, with a `$` instead of `col()`

```
val x = "id"
df.select(col(s"$x"))
```

This gives me an error

```
df.select($s"$x")
```

But this works -- How is it working without the `s` prefix? And is this the correct way?

```
df.select($"$x")
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is correct `$"$x"` and will return column `col("id")`. It's working because the method `$` is defined like this in [SQLImplicits](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLImplicits.scala#L42):

```scala
implicit class StringToColumn(val sc: StringContext) {
  def $(args: Any*): ColumnName = {
    new ColumnName(sc.s(args: _*))
  }
}
```

As you can see, we call [StringContext.sc](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/StringContext.html#s(args:Any*):String) method which does the string interpolation.

Comment: Got it, but I feel they should have kept it consistent with method `col`. Now its one more quirk to remember using spark scala